# Не добавляеться класс через jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня есть код:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
            width: 300,
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
        }).on("select2:select", function (){
            let first=$('.select2-selection__rendered');
        changeColor(first);
        }).on('select2:open', function (){
            addBlack();
        });
    let firstTwo=$('.select2-selection__rendered');
    changeColor(firstTwo);
    function changeColor(elem){
        let list = elem[0].classList;
        if(list.length > 1){
           elem.removeClass(list[1]);
        }
        let a = elem[0].innerText;

        switch(a){
            case 'Kiev':
            elem.addClass('black-circle');
            break;
            case 'Odessa':
            elem.addClass('red-circle');
            break;
            case 'Harkiv':
            elem.addClass('green-circle');
            break;
        }
    }
    function addBlack(){
    let kiev = $('.select2-results__options').eq(0).children().eq(0);
    kiev.addClass('black-circle');
    console.log(kiev)
    }
});
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при открытии списка возле текста появился кружок:
- на первом элементе черный,
- на втором красный,
- на третьем зеленый

Когда я вывожу в консоль его классы, то мне пишет, что есть класс `black-circle`, но кружок не появляется.

```
css:
.select2-selection__rendered{
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.black-circle::before{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 360px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    background: black;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.red-circle::before{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 360px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    background: red;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.green-circle::before{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 360px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    background: green;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Напиши полный пример с версткой

Answer (score 1):

```
'black-circle' != 'black-list'
```

- Вы перепутали названия классов.